# The use of strncmp and memcmp

Tags: memcmp, strncmp

Does

```
if(strncmp(buf, buf2, 7) == 0)
```

do the same thing as

```
if(memcmp(buf, buf2, 7) == 0)
```

`buf` and `buf2` are char* arrays or similar.

I was going to append this to another question but then decided perhaps it was better to post it separately. Presumably the answer is either a trivial "yes" or if not then what is the difference?

(I found these functions from online documentation, but wasn't sure about `strncmp` because the documentation was slightly unclear.)

Answer (score 8):

Like `strcmp()`, `strncmp()` is for comparing *strings*, therefore it stops comparing when it finds a string terminator in at least one argument.  Any differences past that point have no effect on the result.  `strncmp()` differs in that it will also stop comparing after the specified number of bytes if it does not encounter a terminator before then.

`memcmp()`, on the other hand, is for comparing blocks of random memory.  It compares up to the specified number of bytes from each block until it finds a difference, regardless of the values of the bytes.  That is, it does not stop at string terminators.

Answer (score 2):

In C and C++ the end of a string is indicated by a byte with value 0.
The function `memcmp` does not care about the end of a strig but will in any case compare exactly the number of bytes specified.

In contrast to that, the function `strncmp` will stop at a byte with value 0 even though the passed number of bytes to compare is not yet reached.

Comment: Ah yes of course - should have noted that in my question

Comment: In addition to the functionality of the method, the implementation of memcmp() may in fact be different in that it may be designed to work in terms of whole words while strncmp() is likely to be implemented with byte reads only. If performance is an issue, memcmp() may be faster.

Comment: Thanks that's also useful to know

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between `strncmp()` and `memcmp()` is that the first is *sensible* to (*stops* at) `'\0'` where the latest is not. If the first 7 bytes of memory from `buf` and `buf2` do not contain a `'\0'` in it, then the behaviour is the same.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[]  = "123\0 12";
    char buf2[] = "123\0 34";

    printf("strncmp(): %d\n", strncmp(buf, buf2, 7));
    printf("memcmp(): %d\n", memcmp(buf, buf2, 7));

    return 0;
}
```

It will output:

```
strncmp(): 0
memcmp(): -2
```

Because `strncmp()` will stop at `buf[3]`, where it'll find a `'\0'`, where `memcmp()` will continue until all 7 bytes are compared.